# pip3 OpenSSL error

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, pip

I just reinstalled python3, and am trying to install some new packages (for example numpy):

`pip3 install numpy`

...but I get this error:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
```

I know this was discussed about 4 years ago, but I wasn't able to implement any of the suggestions. Something is wrong with my openssl library but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)